# Basemap Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area Plot: strange artefact

Tags: projection, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to use the following code to plot gridded data in the Pacific hemisphere; however, there seems to be a weird artifact as the code below demonstrates. I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to show where I'm going wrong with the setup. Thank you.

```
LON_0 = -160
LAT_0 = 20

plt.close()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.6,11.6))

ax = plt.subplot()

lats = np.linspace(90,-90,181)
lons = np.linspace(180,-180,361)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)

m = Basemap(width=18000000, height=18000000,
            lat_ts=LAT_0, lat_0=LAT_0, lon_0=LON_0,
            ax=ax, projection='laea',
            resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
data =np.sin(lons*5*math.pi/180.)**2+np.sin(lats*5*math.pi/180.)**2

shiftedLons,shiftedData = m.shiftdata(lons, data,
                                      lon_0=LON_0)
px,py = m(shiftedLons, lats)

cbinfo = m.pcolormesh(px, py, shiftedData, cmap='rainbow')
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JkzX.png)

Comment: Weird. I tried using **increasing** `lats` and `lons` instead, but that only shifts the artifact to the bottom of the plot. Also, `pcolormesh` expects the x,y indices to be **grid boundaries** rather than midpoints. But fixing that does not help either. If you can, use `contourf` instead. Map projection is a tricky thing...